# A Drupal.behaviors stops working when I update the module

Tags: 9, javascript

I have checked the field_ui core module to understand how to update my code, but it doesn't seems to work.

This is the code.

```js
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  Drupal.behaviors.custommoduleAnalytics = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      console.log('hello world');
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

This is the library field code.

```yaml
custommodule_analytics:
  js:
    js/custommodule_library.js: {}
    js/custommodule_analytics.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal.ajax
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
    - core/jquery.once
```

I use `hook_page_attachments()` to load the file.

If I look in the browser inspector, it shows that the file loads when the page is loaded, but I don't see `'hello world'` printed from `console.log()`.
The weirdest thing is that this module worked without any issues in version 8.x, and now that I'm updating it to Drupal 9 or 10, it does not work.

Comment: Are you sure that custommodule_analytics library was attached on your page?

Comment: @Vanish , Yes, If I check the network in my browser I can find the request with a 200 and the response show the code.

Comment: Show the hook_page_attachments implementation in the Question.

Answer (score 2):

Jquery.once doesnt exist in d10
Use core/once